# Why is match better than scan when looking for substrings?

Tags: ruby, regex

Why does `scan` not work as well as `match`? I like `scan`, it returns an array which is convenient.

Here is method and calls and puts and I dont know why:

```
def getEmail(url)
        begin
        @@src = getUrl(url).encode("UTF-8")
        @emails = @@src.to_s.scan(/([a-z0-9_\.-]+@[a-z0-9_\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})/)
        rescue Exception => e
            puts e
        end
        @emails = Array.new

        pp @email
        puts "^^^^ SCAN"

        /([a-z0-9_\.-]+@[a-z0-9_\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})/.match(@@src.to_s)
        pp Regexp.last_match
        puts "^^^^ MATCH"

        begin
        @@src = getUrl(url + "/contacts")
        @emails = @@src.to_s.scan(/([a-z0-9_\.-]+@[a-z0-9_\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})/)
        pp @email
        puts "^^^^ SCAN"
        rescue Exception => e
            puts e
        end

        /([a-z0-9_\.-]+@[a-z0-9_\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6})/.match(@@src.to_s)
        pp Regexp.last_match
        puts "^^^^ MATCH"
    end     


@t = Tools.new
@t.getEmail("http://ligasound.designb2b.ru")
```

RESULTS:

```
== request http://ligasound.designb2b.ru
nil
^^^^ SCAN
#<MatchData "liga@mail.ru" 1:"liga@mail.ru">
^^^^ MATCH
 == request http://ligasound.designb2b.ru/contacts
nil
^^^^ SCAN
#<MatchData "liga@mail.ru" 1:"liga@mail.ru">
^^^^ MATCH
```

Why?

Comment: You should not expect readers to have much interest in helping you when they are required to study your code to try to figure what your question is. Please edit to explain, in words, at the beginning, what your question is and how the code that follows relates to the question. (Thanks for the edit, @tadman.)

Comment: There's a couple of things to note here: Try using regular `@var` instance variables and not `@@class` ones out of habit. Ruby also strongly encourages the use of all lower-case method names and variables like `get_email`. Third: `x@google` *is* a valid email address, so your regular expression will miss on a bunch of new, really quirky domains that are showing up.

Comment: `scan` doesn't require the `(...)` capture operator, everything in it is captured by default.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland In the top my question. WHY SCAN WORSE THAN MATCH.

Comment: @tadman Okay, I will change my habbits.

Comment: @tadman Scan doesn't require WHAT? How it can fix problem?

Comment: Its not duplicate. The mail question WHY scan with same regexp NOT GET me results. But match return result. And its from web site where absolutely exist email address.

Comment: @rogersnest Easy on the all-caps YELLING.